# Titanium to Xamarin DB Export

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, titanium

I rewrote an app that used to be in Titanium and need to access the db from the old app. They have the same app identifiers and everything.

in Titanium the app db was stored like this:

```
Ti.Database.install('/db/dbName.db', 'dbName');
```

in Xamarin I'm storing it like this:

```
string documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string db = Path.Combine (documents, "mydb.db");
SqlConnection.CreateFile (db);
```

I need to be able access the data from the Titanium location. Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run your Titanium app in the simulator and check to see where it is creating the db file?  That should give you some guidance.

I'd suggest trying Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments + "/db/dbName.db", but you might have to do some trial and error.

The [Titanium docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database-method-install) describe where they store the db file for various versions of the framework

Comment: I actually tried that path. it doesn't look like that one is it. I've also tried the `Personal` one as well

Comment: I think you're going to have to hunt around on the sim (or a device) to figure out what the actual path is

Comment: This is what Titanium says, but I don't know how to get to this path from Xamarin:
Titanium says:
`var db1 = Ti.Database.install('mydb1', 'mydb1Installed');
The file is copied to the default database location with a file extension of sql.

On simulator

/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ios_version/Applications/apple_app_id/Library/Private Documents/mydb1Installed.sql (Titanium 1.8.0.1)
On device
/Applications/apple_app_id/Library/Private Documents/mydb1Installed.sql (Titanium 1.8.0.1)`

Comment: The above was found here : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database-method-install

Comment: I believe that's what Personal maps to.  Have you looked in a "db" subfolder within Personal, since you are using "/db/" in your Titanium code?

Comment: Yes, no love on that front; but I believe the Titanium code with `/db/` refers to the location of the db inside the project itself. So install the database that is located at `/db/dbName` to the local file system. I am starting my quest through the file directory love

Comment: I figured it out (see my answer). I marked your answer because I wouldn't have found it without the link from Titanium. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xcode's Organizer to see all application on your device.

You can then select your application and see all its files, you can even download all your application data this way.

See Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/copy_app_data_from_sandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH14-SW1) for this Xcode organizer feature.

Answer (score 1):

I had to look at the Titanium documentation (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database-method-install) Which allowed me to find it along with browsing the iOS Simulator application bundle as @poupou pointed out.

This article from Xamarin allowed me to find the `Library` folder then navigate to the `Private Documents` folder inside that (which Titanium created). http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system

Remember that everything is case sensitive.

Here's basically how I did it:

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var library = Path.Combine (documents, "..", "Library");
var legacyData = Path.Combine (library, "Private Documents", "legacyDB.sql"); // Titanium adds the .sql to the end of file names
```

Comment: I chose @Jason's answer because his link to the Titanium doc helped the most.